# Would I be needing a Wi-Fi modem or a Wi-Fi dongle to share internet from desktop to a tablet

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wifi-configuration

My desktop doesn't have Wi-Fi connectivity; all it has is a wired Ethernet broadband connection. I would like to bridge this connection to my tablet and other Wi-Fi devices. Would I be needing one of those tiny Wi-Fi dongles or should I change my Cable modem to a wireless one?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What tablet is this? What desktop is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a wireless router would simplify things a bit, so that's an option. Another option is using a wireless dongle on your desktop and running a software router (this is a built-in function in windows 7 and 8, it just needs a graphic interface). It depends on what kind of range you want, a physical wireless router will have a bigger range than a dongle, and will be more stable with multiple devices used simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wireless router option only.

Plug your internet feed into it.  Then plug your computer into one of the jacks in the back of your router which feeds out internet.

You'll love it.  Merry xmas.